# How to use indexOf method to set the data according?

Tags: angularjs, json, fusioncharts

Hi everyone I'm working on Angular fusion chart. I would like to  set  the data according to the product(json data) i have. But here i face an  issue while using indexof method in  my  fusion chart.

Let me share my  json  data :

```
[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
```

Let  me explain  you  clearly , i need to  set the data according  to the product,  which  you  can see in the json . Each  product  has its own bucket, allocatedAccount and collectedAccount. But  my  chart is showing  a jumbled data. I need to  set according to the product.

Let me show you  the script :

```
$scope.generate = function() {

  $scope.searchResults = false
  $scope.showLoader = true
  var data = reportService.allocationCollection($scope.query).success(function(data) {
     console.log(data.bucket)
    var products = [];
    var buckets = [];
    var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};

    var seriesItem = {};
    var catHolder = {};
    var valHolder = {};
    var valCollection = [];
    var allocatedCollection = [];
    var collectedCollection = [];
    var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];

    var tempDataSet = {};
    var maxYaxisVal = 0;

      $scope.dataset2 = data


      for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
         //console.log(data[i].bucket)

        if (data[i].allocatedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        }
        if (data[i].collectedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].collectedAccount;
        }

        console.log(products);
        if ((products.indexOf(data[i].product) == -1) || (i == (data.length -1))) {
          item = {};
          item["label"] = "Allocated\t\tCollected(" + data[i].product +")";
          item["font"] = "Arial";
          item["fontsize"] = "15";

          catObject.push(item);
          products.push(data[i].product);
        }
         //console.log(data[i].bucket);
        if ((i == (data.length - 1))) {
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
          allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);console.log()
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
          collectedCollection.push(valHolder);
        }
        if ((buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket)== -1) || (i == (data.length -1))) {               
            // console.log(data[i].bucket)
          if (buckets.length > 0) {
            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i].bucket + "allocated";
            seriesItem["data"] = allocatedCollection;
            allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(seriesItem));
            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i].bucket + "collected";

            seriesItem["data"] = collectedCollection;
            collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
            collectedCollection = [];
            allocatedCollection = [];
            //console.log(allocatedDataSet)
          }
          buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
          //console.log(buckets.length);
        }
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
        collectedCollection.push(valHolder);


      }
      catHolder["category"] = catObject;
      catCollection.push(catHolder);


      tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;

      dataSet = [];
      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      tempDataSet = {};
      tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;

      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      $scope.categories = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
      $scope.attrs.yaxismaxvalue = maxYaxisVal;
      console.log($scope.attrs.yaxismaxvalue)

    $scope.showLoader = false;
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 'slow');
    }, 200);

    $scope.results = data;

   console.log($scope.query.product);
    if ($scope.results.length > 0) {


      $scope.searchResults = true
        //console.log("hi");
      _.forEach($scope.results.entities, function(obj) {
        console.log("hi");
        obj.isChecked = false;
      });
      console.log("hi1");
      $scope.view_data = $scope.results.slice($scope.skip, $scope.items + $scope.skip);
      //console.log("hi2");
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.results.length;
      console.log(data);

      $scope.results = data;
      //$scope.results = $filter('orderByValue')(data);
      // called on header click
      } else {
      $scope.searchResults = false
      notificationFactory.warning('No results Found')
      $scope.showLoader = false
    }



  }).error(function(data) {
    notificationFactory.warning('Error Searching Reports')
    console.log(data);
  })
 }
```

And my Html for fusion chart:

```
<div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" chart="  {{attrs}}" categories="{{categories}}" dataset="{{dataset}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic was not correctly implemented for Multi-series stacked column chart. The resultant JSON structure of the code does not comply to the supported format for the said chart hence data was getting wrongly visualized for both the categories.

Please visit the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Akash008/u7ju71oo/39/

Please check the modified script

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.chartoptions = {
    "dataEmptyMessage": "No data to display <br> Do these steps..."
  };
  data =[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
$scope.attrs = {
                "palette":"3",
                "numdivlines":'3',
                "numberprefix": "",
                "useRoundEdges":"1",
                "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
                "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "yaxismaxvalue": "1000",
                "showLegend":"1",
                "showborder": "0",
                "labelDisplay": "wrap", 
                "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
                "maxLabelHeight":"150"
             };
var products = [];
var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};
     var catHolder = {};
      var buckets = [];
      var dataSet=[];
       var seriesItem = {};
       var productWiseAllocationarr=[];
       var productWiseCollectionarr= [];
        var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];
      var tempDataSet = {};
      var allseries={};
      var collseries={};
      var allocatedData = [];
    var collectedData = [];
     
     for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (products.indexOf(data[i].product)== -1)
                {
                    item = {};
                    item["label"] = "Allocated\tCollected   " + data[i].product;
                    item["font"] = "Arial";
                    item["fontsize"] = "15";
           
                    catObject.push(item);
                    products.push(data[i].product);
                    catHolder["category"] =  catObject ;
            
                }
                 if (buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket)==-1)
                {
                
                         buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
                }
               
            
     }
     for(var j=0;j<products.length;j++)
     {
     for(var p=0;p<data.length;p++)
     {
     if(data[p].product==products[j])
     {
     var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].allocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].collectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);
     }
     }
     }
     for(var b =0;b<buckets.length;b++)
     {
      allseries = {};
       allseries.name =buckets[b]+"allocated";
       allseries.data=[];
        collseries = {};
       collseries.name =buckets[b]+"collected";
       collseries.data=[];
     for(var pr=0;pr< productWiseAllocationarr.length;pr++)
     {
       if(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {
      
       allseries.data.push(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].amount);
       
        
       }
        if( productWiseCollectionarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {
       
       collseries.data.push(productWiseCollectionarr[pr].amount);
      
        
       }
     }
      allocatedData.push(allseries);
       collectedData.push(collseries);
     }
    for(var w=0;w<allocatedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] = allocatedData[w].name;
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<allocatedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=allocatedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
        allocatedData[w].data;
        allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
       
         for(var w=0;w< collectedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] =  collectedData[w].name;
        
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<collectedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=collectedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
         collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
     tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;

           
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet = {};
            tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
   catCollection.push(catHolder);
     
      $scope.categories  = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
        });
```

```html
<html ng-app="HelloApp">

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
         <div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" dataSource="{{dataSource}}" categories="{{categories}}" chart="{{attrs}}" dataFormat= 'json' dataset="{{dataset}}" events="events">
                          </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```